# how to perform hourly backup of mysql MyISAM tables

Tags: mysql, myisam, database-backups

I have a wamp local server with only MyISAM tables, Total size is 350 MB and increases by about 10 MB per day. Would like to have a hourly backup solution. As recently WAMP server crashed and lost data.Should I create a trigger or schedule a task or use some utility it would be great if someone can guide. So that database backup is takeon either on local network or on different  partition of server HDD. Have mirror RAID enabled on the server.

Comment: stored procedures, cron, there's a lot of available resources for this. Also, while not relevant to your question, why still using MyISAM?

Comment: my default setup was MYISAM so never thought to migrate to any other format.  But if  switch over has benefits will love to change my tables as it is in early stages. varchar search is a requirement. And need a easy way to hourly backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since InnoDB does not lose data in a crash, and since you are talking about backing up a lot of data, and you are in the 'early stages', the only *real* answer to your question is to switch to InnoDB.

When the server crashes, MyISAM almost always leaves some indexes in need of `REPAIR TABLE`.  This problem vanishes with InnoDB.

If the server crashes in the middle of a multi-row `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` on a MyISAM table, some rows will be done and other rows won't be.  And you have no way to know how much was done.  With InnoDB, the entire query is "rolled back", making it as if it had not occurred.  Very predictable.

See [*my tips*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/)
 on converting.

For better recovery from a crash where the server cannot be restarted at all, consider Replication.

Comment: Have converted the tables into InnoDB.Suggest the best practice for  innodb tables backup

Comment: Percona's Xtrabackup.

Comment: percona backup is for  Xamp, I am using Wamp windows machine. Any alternative suggesstions